# React Native - "Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got undefined" - importing custom library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

Alright, I need to hack/tweak this library, so Im trying to import the **not transpiled** version by downloading the repo and importing: https://github.com/nicotroia/react-native-floating-action-menu#readme

All the paths are correct and the structure of the folder is:

[image]

When I do `import { FloatingMenu } from './FloatingMenu/components/FloatingMenu';` I get the error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got
> undefined

Says to "Check the render method of App." What is wrong here?

Comment: Most probably a wrong `import` issue. You're not importing from the library itself there but from a custom component. How did you write that component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the non-transpiled code you're using is [this file](https://github.com/nicotroia/react-native-floating-action-menu/blob/master/src/components/FloatingMenu/index.js), the issue is that it's got a default export, but you're using a named import, not a default import. The fix is to change this:

```
import { FloatingMenu } from './FloatingMenu/components/FloatingMenu';
```

To this:

```
import FloatingMenu from './FloatingMenu/components/FloatingMenu';
```